# React: Cleanest way of accessing component without using "this"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to access a React component within a function nested within a a handler function.

When in a nested function `this` does not give a reference to the component

so I explicitly declare it instead of doing the usual `this.setState(...)`

Is there a cleaner way to do this than my following code?

```
React.createClass({

    uploadImage : function() {
    ...
    var componentReference = this

    xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {if(request.readyState==4) {
        componentReference.setState({uploadStatus: request.status});
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use e.g. https://lodash.com/docs#bind

Comment: Some folks would argue that keeping a separate reference rather than binding `this` left, right and centre ***is*** the cleanest way to write code.

Comment: Surely a fat arrow function would be the best, failing that then bind.

Comment: Just found this great explanation of the options: [link](http://jsforallof.us/2014/07/08/var-that-this/)

Answer (score 4):

This is just how JavaScript works:

1. You'll have to keep a reference to whatever you want to access in a function that's called in a different context (like you implemented it with your variable)…

or

2. …bind what `this` points to at the time the function is called. There's no need to use a library (like lodash) because ECMAScript 5.1 has his built-in, and you can use it in any recent-ish browser (Chrome 7+, Firefox 4+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

If you need to support older browsers, you can implement a `bind` function yourself, see for example Underscore.js' `Function.prototype.bind` implementation: http://underscorejs.org/#bind

Answer (score 2):

The most idiomatic way to do this is with the native [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method, no libraries required:

```
React.createClass({
    uploadImage : function() {
        // ...

        xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(request.readyState == 4) {
                this.setState({ uploadStatus: request.status });
            }
        }.bind(this)

        // ...
    }
})
```

`.bind(this)` sets the context of `this` *inside* the `.onreadystatechange` closure. It's a bit like passing the scope to the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using e.g. [lodash](https://lodash.com), you can do it like this:

```
xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = _.bind(function () {
    if ( request.readyState == 4 ) {
        this.setState({ uploadStatus: request.status });
    }
}, this);
```

Or, if you use jQuery, you can [proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Function bind method in plain old JS like function() {}.bind(this) and then "this" inside your function will be your React component.

You can see the definition of bind() here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `onreadystatechange` handler on the “class” itself, profiting from React’s auto binding.

You could also keep a reference to `setState`, but I’m not sure whether that’s auto-bound as well. Try it out.

Last but not least, since you are probably using a transpiler anyway, you could use an ES6 arrow function. Arrow functions use the “outer” value of `this` (lexical `this`)

Comment: Whoever downvoted my answer: could you please elaborate so that I can learn?